# Python - How to get keys with same values in a dictionary/

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict:

```
{'Key_1': ['Value_1'], 'Key_2': ['Value_1', 'Value_2'], 'Key_3': ['Value_2'], 'Key_4': ['Value_3']}
```

I would like to get the keys with the same values e.g., an output like:

```
Key_1 and Key_2 have same Value_1
Key_2 and Key_3 have same Value_2
```

I tried this to get the common values:

```
list_1 = []
output = []
for value in dictionary.values():
    for x in value:
         if x in list_1:
            if not x in output:
                output.append(x)
         else:
             list_1.append(x)
```

With this I get the common values but not the corresponding keys.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have u tried making a dictoanary but with key as values and values as key

Comment: You can't always do that because dict keys must be hashable and lists are not hashable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = {'Key_1': ['Value_1'], 'Key_2': ['Value_1', 'Value_2'], 'Key_3': ['Value_2'], 'Key_4': ['Value_3']}

out = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    for vv in v:
        out.setdefault(vv, []).append(k)

for k, v in out.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        print('{} have same {}'.format(' and '.join(v), k))
```

Prints:

```
Key_1 and Key_2 have same Value_1
Key_2 and Key_3 have same Value_2
```